# jquery color variation

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I need to produce all 255/256 color variations of a given color, is there some advice to start, or a jQuery lib to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "variations"?

Comment: Does this come close? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177826/simple-color-variation

Comment: There is actually only one color.  It just has 16 million variations.

Comment: @recursive, that color is octarine of course.

Comment: Wasn't that a greenish-yellow purple?

Comment: For example, of a giving color get all the variation set of colors: http://0to255.com/000000

Comment: @josoroma you are still not defining what you mean by "variation". Variation in hue? Brightness? Red / Green / Blue component?

Comment: @josoroma it would be very helpful to those trying to answer your question (myself included) if you could provide examples of the input you expect and the output you'd like to produce.

Comment: For example, the color #CC0000 generates this variation: http://0to255.com/CC0000 this the kind of variaton what im looking for any hex giving color. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're talking about performing some sort of math on the individual red, green, and blue channels (I think that's what you mean by "color") of a particular color value. I can only guess at your desired input and output values, but here's an example to start, manipulating the values in RGB space*. Assuming your input is a hex number:

```
var color = 0xFFD700, // "gold"

    // separate the channels using bitmasks
    redValue = color & 0xFF0000, // redValue is 0xFF0000
    greenValue = color & 0x00FF00, // greenValue is 0x00D700
    blueValue = color & 0x0000FF; // blueValue is 0x000000

// now we can manipulate each color channel independently
var lessRed = redValue - 0x010000,
    moreBlue = blueValue + 0x000001,
    newColor = lessRed + greenValue + moreBlue; // newColor is 0xFED701
```

So, one way to produce an array of all colors produced by varying the red channel, holding green and blue constant:

```
var colors = [],
    startColor = 0x00D700,
    endColor = 0xFFD700,
    incr = 0x010000;

while (startColor <= endColor)
{
    colors.push(startColor);
    startColor = startColor + incr;
}

// print the hex values
var i, len = colors.length, out = [];
for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    out.push('0x' + colors[i].toString(16))
}
console.log(out.join('\n'))
```

If your input is a string, you just need to convert it to a number first.

```
var input = 'FFD700',
    hexValue = parseInt(input, 16);
console.log(hexValue.toString(10)); // prints: 16766720
console.log(hexValue.toString(16)); // prints: FFD700
```

Oh, and no jQuery needed!

---

`*` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141855/programmatically-lighten-a-color/141861#141861), RGB space may not be the best color space to use, but based on your question, I *think* it is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

I found two interesting concepts:

Im going to play a little with the concepts from:
http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/

$.xcolor.lighten and $.xcolor.darken

Another interesting reading:
http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/true-color-darkening-and-lightening.html

But the last one doestn work with Red, Green and Blue:
FF0000
00FF00
0000FF

Maybe needs just a little fix to accept the 3 "real" Red, Green anb Blue hex values, but im lost.